# Set a cron job to a specific timezone on Centos 7

Tags: cron, timezone, centos7

I'm trying to set the cron jobs to run on a specific timezone, but I think I'm missing something.

I've tried to add TZ (And CRON_TZ) on top of the jobs in the /var/spool/cron/ file, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
TZ=Europe/Rome 
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/user/folder/file.php
```

I've installed CWP7pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the manual:

Every * means something:

```
    minute 0-59
    hour 0-23
    day of month 1-31
    month 1-12 (or names, see below)
    day of week 0-7 (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
```

if you want every minute use this 
        */1

example:

```
     */15 * * 1 * means every 15 minutes on the 1st day of the month
```

Edit **/etc/crontab** or use

```
    crontab -e (edit)
```

CRON_TZ should be used instead of TZ or use TZ inline

```
    */15 * * 1 * TZ=Europe/Rome echo "do something"
```